# Can I set a local var to 'this' to reference it inside an anonymous callback function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, this

I would like to reference 'this' in a callback function, but there is no guarantee that 'this' will refer to the correct object. Is it appropriate to create a local variable referencing 'this' and use that variable inside the anonymous function?

Example:

```
var MyClass = function (property) {
  this.property = property;
  someAsynchronousFunction(property, function (result) {
    this.otherProperty = result; // 'this' could be wrong
  });
};
```

The problem is, the asynchronous function may call the provided callback from an arbitrary context (which is often outside of my control, e.g. when using libraries).

My proposed solution is:

```
var MyClass = function (property) {
  this.property = property;
  var myClass = this;
  someAsynchronousFunction(property, function (result) {
    myClass.otherProperty = result; // references the right 'this'
  });
};
```

But I was looking to see if there are other strategies, or if this solution is problematic in any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've done is the classical way of making sure you refer to the correct object, <strike>though you should define it locally</strike>, i.e.:

```
function(property) {
    var that = this;

    someFunc(function(result) {
        that.property = whatever;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, in modern browsers you can bind it explicitly:

```
someFunc(function(result) {
    this.property = whatever;
}.bind(this));
```

See also: [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Libraries such as jQuery support the latter functionality as a proxy function that more browsers support and can be simplified into this reusable function:

```
function proxy(fn, ctx)
{
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(ctx, arguments);
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
someFunc(proxy(function(result) {
    this.property = whatever;
}, this));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's fine, but don't use an implicit global variable as you did, use a local variable:

```
var myClass = this;
```

Comment: I was going to add an alternative with `bind`, but Jack did it first! :)